# Значение в объекте по умолчанию при деструктуризации

Tags: javascript, объекты

Можете, пожалуйста объяснить что происходит в данном тестовом коде.

```js
const { w: width = 400, h: height = 500 } = { w: 800 }

console.log("width", width);
console.log("height", height);
```

Я понимаю, что там назначены дефолтные значения, но как это грамотно озвучить не понимаю.

Comment: Деструктуризируется объект. Для ключа w создается переменная width и если ключа в объекте нет, то переменной будет присвоено значение по умолчанию. Для h аналогично

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустим, у нас есть объект, в котором много ключей. Мы не хотим(по каким то причинам) по коду обращаться к ключам так: `obj.key1`(а вдруг ключа нет, тогда придется постоянно проверять на наличие его), а хотим выделить переменную.

Как бы мы это сделали:

```
const key1 = obj.key2 || 'defaultValue';
```

Если ключей много, которые нам нужны? И не хочется для каждого писать const и т.д., вот тут на помощь приходит деструктуризация

```js
// Наш объект
const x = {
  a: 100,
  b: 200,
  d: 500
}

// Можно выделить нужные нам ключи в переменные по их названию
const {a, b, c} = x;
console.log(a, b, c); // c - undefined

// Если мы хотим изменить название переменных, то это можно сделать через :
// Для задания значения по умолчанию, ставим = и указываем значение
const {a: y = 300, c: z = 400} = x;
console.log(y, z)
```

Как видно из примера, мы не используем `x.d` из примера(ну не нужен он нам), однако используем(условно) `x.c`, которого нет в исходом объекте и наш `x.c` становится переменной `z` со значением 400